# Clean and Nil-clean ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A ring with unity is said to be clean if every element $r$ can be written as $r=u+e$, where $u$ is a unit and $e$ is an idempotent and nil-clean if we can write $r=b+e$ where $b$ is  nilpotent and $e$ is idempotent. Is it true that
a ring $R$ is (nil-)clean if and only if, for each $a \in R$, $a = b − e$ where $b$ is a unit (resp., nilpotent)? My attempt:

We have
$$a=b-e$$ 
implies
$$a=(b-1)+(1-e)$$

If $b$ is nilpotent and $e$ is idempotent then $b-1$ is unit and $1-e$ is idempotent.
This does not conclude much.  [Here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiP5uy5sb3YAhXIuI8KHdWkCgoQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1412.5544&usg=AOvVaw0DQeiVh2qF8gNGvtAqbX9N) is the link for the statement I am interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is either a unit or nilpotent, then so is $-x$. Since every element can be written as $c+e$ where $c$ is unit/nilpotent and $e$ idempotent, then, in particular, so can $-a$. Thus, we have $-a = c + e$ so $a = -c - e$, but $-c$ is also a unit/nilpotent, call it $b$, and we have $a = b - e$ where $b=-c$ is a unit/nilpotent. Doing the same thing again will give you the converse.

Comment: Ah! missed that. Thank you @Derek